# I'm using Magento 2.4.6 and want to allow customers to log in permanently as long as I don't hit the logout button

Tags: php, session, magento2, session-cookies, magento2.4

I am trying to achieve a login duration of 2 days or (a period of time) for customers in Magento 2.4.6. I tried adjusting the "Online Session Lifetime" value to control the duration of customer sessions in Magento 2.4.6 but it's not working!

as you can see in the image i tried to change the default value but it didn't work :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is by checking and potentially adjusting the php.ini configuration file.

There are two settings in here:

1. 'session.gc_maxlifetime' This setting represents the maximum lifetime of a session in seconds.
2. 'session.cookie_lifetime' This setting determines the lifetime of the session cookie in seconds. If the value is set to 0 the cookie will expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).